# Save As a new Excel file changes links on dependent file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two Excel files.  One is linked to the other.

If I take the link source `.xls` and save that as another file, then the dependent file's links are pointed automatically by Excel to that new source file rather than the original source file.

I want to prevent Excel from helpfully doing that:  If the source file is saved as another file, I want the dependent file's links to that original source retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save and close the dependent file first *before* saving the source as another file.

Comment: Another way is to open the each workbook in separate instances of Excel. In Windows 7, you can quickly open another instance of Excel by middle-clicking its tab on the taskbar. However, you won't be able to add any new links between them.